# Title text color for header

Tags: website-design, color-theory

I have this header image:

[image]

And I'm trying to find the best colors for the text of the title. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

White or yellow would work here.

Comment: I second either of these.

Comment: I was thinking yellow myself.  If you wanted to do white, I'd darken up the foreground gray a bit and lose 50% of the saturation on the blue.  I guess it depends on whether or not you want the text to go over both the buildings and the sky, or just the sky.

Answer (score 5):

To clarify, does the title sit in the header? Do you want your headings to use the same color?

I normally do a test to actually see what works best. I made a copy of your header and added some of the suggested colors. I also added drop shadows and outer glow, just experimenting.

My decision would be based on what I want to do with headings. If I wanted to use the blue for headings, I might use a glow around a blue title to simulate clouds. Or white with a drop shadow for most contrast. I like adding a layer style in this case, to help separate the title from the blue sky, since it uses pretty intense color.

[image: Banner with title samples]

Comment: Great suggestion, and thanks a lot for the examples !

Answer (score 0):

I think that depends on other elements from the context. But orange is good if you want to emphasize the title.

Answer (score 0):

Yellow would be a great color as suggested by others. The yellow stimulates the glow of the city in the background. It could also stimulate a moon or stars. The yellow title would be better with drop shadows. The shadow on the outside of the title would give a sense of the title hanging in the sky. The viewer would feel as if the title was hanging in the sky and illuminating the whole background.